# Problems with Daniell cell

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, erratum

In [Zemansky and Dittman's book](http://curso.unach.mx/~rarceo/docs/zemansky_En.pdf) on thermodynamics, pages 41–43, the authors discuss the Daniell cell as a thermodynamic system.

Their cell consists of two saturated $\ce{CuSO4}$ and $\ce{ZnSO4}$ solutions separated by a porous wall, with a copper strip dipped in the first and a zinc in the second, and with salt crystals in the bottom of each solution.

[image]

There are two problems:

The first is that the authors say that the cell is rechargeable, whereas [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniell_cell) says it not, so who is right?

The second is that the book states that in discharging mode:

> If the electrolytes are saturated solutions, a current driven by the chemical reaction at constant temperature and pressure will not alter the concentrations of the electrolytes.

Well I can't understand how this happens. I can imagine that the $\ce{ZnSO4}$ solution will be over-saturated and the extra amount of it will deposit on the crystals,  but how can the other solution keep a constant concentration?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why would it change? It is a saturated solution. If some CuSO4 vanishes, more will dissolve and keep it saturated.

Comment: @IvanNeretin so $\ce{CuSO4}$ dissolves spontaneously till it reaches saturation ?

Comment: Of course it does, like all compounds do.

Comment: @IvanNeretin forgive my ignorance, i clearly know nothing on this, but would the deposit dissolve even if the solution wasn't saturated at the beginning ?

Comment: Of course it would. That's the meaning of the word "saturated". Unless the solution is saturated, more compound would dissolve.